# How to handle captcha in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have created a test plan for a user for a web application. The test plan is running as expected, but on the registration screen, the user has to enter a captcha. I'm not able to handle it from Jmeter.

Comment: Please frame the question with concrete details. What have you tried? What is failing ?

Comment: I have created a test plan for a user for a web application. Test plan is running as expected but on registration screen, user has to enter capcha. I m not able to handle it from Jmeter. After goggling I found a solution on stack over flow.

Comment: I found this on stack overflow:
 1. Create a Beanshell Sampler

In it, the following code displays the captcha and waits for user input

filenameOrURL = new URL("${captchaimage}");
image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(filenameOrURL);
Icon icon = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(image);

JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Enter Captcha", 0, 0, null);
String captcha = pane.showInputDialog(null, "Captcha", "Captcha", 0, icon, null, null);

Answer (score 2):

Solution is here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964358/jmeter-testcases-which-can-handle-captcha

Or you can disable captcha from code before test.

Answer (score -1):

The whole point of adding captcha security is to stop an automated tool to access the website.

It is not completely possible, but if you are able to handle that using Jmeter or another tool then its security bug as anyone can run an Automated test on your environment.

There are some ways to manage/handle, you need to get the following things from app/ development experts:

1. To disable CAPTCHA validation for testing purpose.
2. To make the CAPTCHA as static- Make certain it sends only the same value 
   each time.
3. To send the CAPTCHA value in server response-(with the intention that you 
   can correlate)
4. Provide the CAPTCHA details which are come in the database in sequence-
   Basically, get it from the database and ensure it happens in series.